# Problem using .htaccess restriction and AJAX

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, restriction

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(includes|config)/ - [F]
```

I encountered a problem when trying to protect the file that processes the login of my system. Since I am using AJAX to improve the user experience, the connection gets restricted. Is there any way to create an intermediate file to bypass this problem? Something like a public folder that calls the original processing file using 'require'... Alternatively, if there's a better solution, I would take it.

Comment: It is unclear, what you actually ask. If your (client side) application logic requires those files to be accessible, then why do you restrict access to them? This sounds like you are trying to work around a restriction you yourself set up. _Why?_

Comment: Even _if_ you succeed in implementing some strange "workaround", then what have you gained? Those files are _again_ accessible, because you need them to be. So you gained absolutely nothing, but invested a lot of time. You should think the other way round: _why_ would you want to restrict access to those files? If that is a security issue, because they contain sensitive data or demonstrate a way to miss use your service, then that is the issue you need to fix. Certainly not by trying to party hide files, but by actually making your implementation clean.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I didn’t understand how to secure my files, I thought this was the best way to restrict the users, sorry. My english is not too good, but basically I was worried about something that can be solved with other methods